# Validate multiple conditions in xpath

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, parent-child, siblings

I got the following HTML table and I need to find the ID of the `tr` which contains `span` whose values are `Action2` and `Server1` and `Tag2`.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="table-layout:fixed;" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId" class="dr-table rich-table ">
    <colgroup span="8"></colgroup>
    <tbody id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:tb">
        <tr class="dr-subtable-row rich-subtable-row dr-subtable-firstrow rich-subtable-firstrow 0">
            <td width="2%" style="padding-left:17px;" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:j_id31" class="dr-subtable-cell rich-subtable-cell ">
                <label class="CollapseRow" onclick="noOfRows(this);" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:expand"></label>
            </td>
            <td style="width:20%" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:TkDesc" class="dr-subtable-cell rich-subtable-cell adjacent TkDescC">
                <span title="Action1" class="adjacentSpan" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:cell-">Action1</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:22%" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:tgt" class="dr-subtable-cell rich-subtable-cell adjacent tgtC">
                <span title="Server1" class="adjacentSpan">Sever1</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:16%" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:tgtDep" class="dr-subtable-cell rich-subtable-cell adjacent tgtDepC">
                <span title="Tag1" class="adjacentSpan">Tag1</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dr-subtable-row rich-subtable-row dr-subtable-firstrow rich-subtable-firstrow 0">
            <td width="2%" style="padding-left:17px;" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:j_id31" class="dr-subtable-cell rich-subtable-cell ">
                <label class="CollapseRow" onclick="noOfRows(this);" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:expand"></label>
            </td>
            <td style="width:20%" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:TkDesc" class="dr-subtable-cell rich-subtable-cell adjacent TkDescC">
                <span title="Action2" class="adjacentSpan" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:cell-">Action2</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:22%" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:tgt" class="dr-subtable-cell rich-subtable-cell adjacent tgtC">
                <span title="Server1" class="adjacentSpan">Server1</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:16%" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:tgtDep" class="dr-subtable-cell rich-subtable-cell adjacent tgtDepC">
                <span title="Tag2" class="adjacentSpan">Tag2</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr class="dr-subtable-row rich-subtable-row dr-subtable-firstrow rich-subtable-firstrow 0">
            <td width="2%" style="padding-left:17px;" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:j_id31" class="dr-subtable-cell rich-subtable-cell ">
                <label class="CollapseRow" onclick="noOfRows(this);" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:expand"></label>
            </td>
            <td style="width:20%" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:TkDesc" class="dr-subtable-cell rich-subtable-cell adjacent TkDescC">
                <span title="Action1" class="adjacentSpan" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:cell-">Action1</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:22%" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:tgt" class="dr-subtable-cell rich-subtable-cell adjacent tgtC">
                <span title="Server2" class="adjacentSpan">Server2</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:16%" id="rtTkFrm:recTkTabId:0:innertable:0:tgtDep" class="dr-subtable-cell rich-subtable-cell adjacent tgtDepC">
                <span title="Tag2" class="adjacentSpan">Tag2</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried following but it was not working as expected

`//id('recentTaskFrm:recTaskTabId')/tbody/tr/td[descendant::span[@title='Action1' and @title='Server2' and @title='Tag2']]/@id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You're querying the wrong `@id` attribute (its `rtTkFrm:recTkTabId`, not `recentTaskFrm:recTaskTabId`).
2. You need to search for multiple descendents with one predicate each. Your query tries to find span elements which title is 'Action1', 'Server2' and 'Tag2' at the same time.
3. You're querying for `@id` attributes of table cells, not rows.

Try this query:

```
//table[@id='rtTkFrm:recTkTabId']/tbody/tr[
  td//span[@title="Action2"]
  and td//span[@title="Server1"]
  and td//span[@title="Tag2"]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the errors. I'm able to fetch the value by having the and condition at `td` level as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `//id('recentTaskFrm:recTaskTabId')/tbody/tr/td[descendant::span[@title='Action1'] and descendant::span[@title='Server2'] and descendant::span[@title='Tag2']]/@id`

Comment: I tried that and it's not finding any matches! When I try only with `Action1` it's returning multiple values but the and condition is not working as expected.